# Tracking not working for both controllers at the same time on Oculus Quest build 7.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Since the last update of Oculus Quest (to build 7.0) I can't move both controllers at the same time in my Unity builds:

- It's only being tracked the "active" controller
- I can switch active controller by pressing the trigger of the
  controller I want to set as active
- This is only happening in builds of my projects in Unity, tracking of
  both controllers works great with Oculus Quest applications (Home,
  YoutubeVR, JobSim, etc.)

[Video showing this behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w8LS.jpg)
(Lightweight VR RP default scene. It's the same behaviour with VRTK example scene)

**Someone else is having this problem? What could be the cause?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

(In Unity project)

1. Oculus > Tools > Remove AndroidManifest.xml
2. Oculus > Tools > Create store-compatible AndroidManifest.xml
3. Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

After Removing and reinstaling AndroidManifest now we can build anything on Quest, always returns